# How to convert/cast varchar to date?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a date column with data type `varchar(mm-dd-yyyy)` in mySQL 5.1. How do I convert it to DATE?

Here is what I have so far -

```
SELECT id, date 
FROM tableName 
WHERE (CAST((SUBSTRING (date FROM 7 FOR 4 )||'/'||SUBSTRING (date FROM 4 FOR 2 )||'/'||SUBSTRING (date FROM 1 FOR 2 )) AS DATE) >= '01/01/2012' ) 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Getting this

> error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM 7 FOR 4 )

Please help.

Comment: Worth noting that the error you are getting is due to DATE being a MySQL keyword. If you're using it as a column name, then you need to surround it with backticks. Or perhaps better, rename your column as "date" isn't necessarily the best descriptor.

Comment: Firstly, why are you storing dates as varchars? Secondly if you are storing them as varchars why are you storing them in a culture specific format and not yyyyMMdd. Thirdly, why are you converting this varchar to a date to compare it to a varchar (`WHERE [Conversion] = '01/01/2012'`)? If it is not too late you should probably alter your tables rather than trying to perform the varchar to date conversion.

Comment: @GarethD - I'm assuming he's converting it to a date, because the given format isn't sortable for his use-case (nearly not sortable at all).  Won't the (string formatted) date he's providing be converted to date during optimization?

Comment: @GarethD, I didn't create this table and at this point I can't alter it either. '01/01/2012' - should be 01/01/2012 (date) not a varchar. That's my mistake - typo there.

Comment: @liquorvicar, yes you are right and I have the columnName just like that in the actual doc. Took it off here for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @X-Zero For sorting I agree, but for the optimiser will only convert '01/01/2012' to a date if it is being compared to a date, for an equal to comparison there is no point in converting a column storing dates in the format dd/MM/yyyy to a date, so the optimiser can implcitly convert a constant in the format dd/MM/yyyy to a date compare the two. A varchar to varchar comparison is no less efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
SELECT id, date 
FROM tableName 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '01/01/2012' 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Although I suspect you will have an easier time using Unix Timestamps

```
SELECT id, date 
FROM tableName 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y')) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('01/01/2012') 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```