# MySQL varchar timestamp column stored two different ways

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, timestamp

I have a table with device data, one of the columns `created_ts` -> `varchar(30)`

The problem: this data in this column contains both linux timestamps and varchars for example:

`1381148885`

and

`2012-09-17 22:13:17`

**How can I query this column for all records with created_ts  > 2013-10-01**

Comment: Do you looked?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date][1]
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583045/how-to-convert-cast-varchar-to-date][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583045/how-to-convert-cast-varchar-to-date

Good work!

Comment: Get rid of the root problem! You should store dates in a `datetime` column. Storing dates in varchar columns lead to problems like the one you have right now and scanning `varchar` columns is also a lot slower than scanning `datetime` columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd opt for distinguishing between the string formats (either 'YYYY-MM-DD' or unix timestamp integer) by checking for a dash character.

I'd consider explicitly converting both of those formats to the `DATE` datatype, using an appropriate conversion. I'd compare the resulting DATE value with the date literal.

Something like this:

```
 WHERE IF(LOCATE('-',t.created_ts,5),              -- which format (yyyy-mm-dd or integer)
          STR_TO_DATE(t.created_ts,'%Y-%m-%d %T'), -- convert yyyy-mm-dd string to date
          FROM_UNIXTIME(t.created_ts)              -- convert string as integer to date
       ) >= '2013-10-01'                           -- compare to date literal
```

Another option would be to convert the string column and the date literal to integer values, and do an integer comparison. (Again, two different conversions for the string column, depending on the format.)

---

NOTE: I included the hh:mm:ss portion in the conversion with the %T.

When no time component is supplied, the time components is assumed to be midnight (zeros) 00:00:00, and that comes into play depending on whether or not we want to consider

```
'2013-10-01 07:34:55' > '2013-10-01 00:00:00'
```

OP query has a greater than comparison. I used a greater than or equal to comparison.

This could all be adjusted, depending on the requirements. We want to be aware that if we aren't careful, some values will get "rounded down" to the previous midnight, and then when we do a greater than comparison, what we're really getting is equivalent to `>= '2013-10-02'`.

My preference is to make it more explicit. It makes it easier for the reader to understand what the query is actually doing.

---

**UPDATE**

I had the arguments in the LOCATE function backwards... the string to search for should be the first argument, the string to be searched is second. That's been corrected in the query above.

Comment: +1 Nice answer @spencer7593 ... first time i see something like this, thanks ;)

Comment: @Robert Rozas: this kind of problem is exactly why we have DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP available as datatypes. Converting the data when it's stored makes our queries to retrieve the data MUCH easier to understand, and also makes it possible to do the retrieval MUCH more efficiently.

Comment: This problem is generated when you use the wrong datatype and the wrong-mixed data format to store your data

Comment: Exactly. The query in my answer isn't a solution, it's a workaround to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: So the locate function is not working for me, I'm not sure why... `select sum(IF(LOCATE(t.created_ts,'-',5),1,0)) total_varchar_ts from a` returns 0 records

Comment: @hagope: yeah, I got the order of the arguments backwards. The string to search for should be first, the string to be searched is the second argument... I'll modify the query in my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  select * from yourTable
  where created_ts > '2013-10-01'
  or from_unixtime(created_ts) > '2013-10-01';
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, because of the string comparison on the column. For example, date values prior to 2001-09-09 represented as unix timestamp are less than 10 digits... UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2001-09-09') = 999993600, convert that to character and store it in the column `'999993600'`, and that will be "greater than" any string starting with `'2013'`.